# How to handle user status change for Discord bot?

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

There are events available `DiscordClient.UserJoined`, `DiscordClient.UserLeft` and `DiscordClient.UserUpdated`. While in first two I can access `e.User.Name` to get name of user who has joined or left the server, the third event does not have this. There is only `e.Server.CurrentUser` which refers to the bot itself or `e.Server.Users` which gives me list of all users. But I don't know for which one the event triggered, thus don't know which one access to.

Let's say I want to create a notification when user comes online (change his/her status from offline to online or vice versa). For `UserJoined` event I can do:

```
client.UserJoined += async (s, e) =>
{
  var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("abc", ChannelType.Text);
  await channel.SendMessage(e.User.Name + " has joined the server!");
}
```

But how can I do this for `UserUpdated` when I have no `User`?

```
client.UserUpdated += async (s, e) =>
{
  var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("abc", ChannelType.Text);
  if(???.Status == "online")
  {
    await channel.SendMessage(???.Name + " has come online!");
  }
}
```

Comment: User is going to be at e.Before and e.After, so to access it use e.After.Name

Comment: This is a bit confusing but now I understand the structure. You are correct. If you write it as an answer I will tag it for you as correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User is going to be at e.Before and e.After, so to access it use e.After.Name